# Measuring one particle on this entangled state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

If we have a normalized entagled state:

$$ |a\rangle=N (|1\rangle|2\rangle+|1\rangle|-2\rangle+|1\rangle|2\rangle-|-1\rangle|2\rangle) $$

Where $|2\rangle, |-2\rangle$  describes particles A and $|1\rangle, |-1\rangle$ particle B.

If we measure this system and find out that particle A is in the state $|2\rangle$, the system will be in a superposition of the states $|1\rangle|2\rangle$ and $|-1\rangle|2\rangle$, right?

How can we write this new state?

Comment: I am assuming you have made a mistake in repeating the products $|1\rangle |2\rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean your state is
$$|1\rangle|2\rangle+|1\rangle|-2\rangle+|-1\rangle|-2\rangle+|-1\rangle|2\rangle $$
(an even superposition of all states)?

In that case, yes, you will have a state that is a superposition of $1\rangle|2\rangle$ and $|-1\rangle|2\rangle $.

You can write the new normalized state as
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 1\rangle|2\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-1\rangle|2\rangle$.